# OpenSSL: decryption with private key _sometimes_ throws "error:02000079:rsa routines::oaep decoding error"

Tags: encryption, openssl, private-key, public-key

We are trying to use openSSL to encrypt a string with a public key, and then decrypt it with the private key.

Curiously, the workflow sometimes works, and sometimes it does not work (for the same keys and texts) and throws an error.

First, the private and public key are generated by:

```
openssl req -newkey rsa:2048 -new -nodes -x509 -days 3650 -keyout key.pem -out cert.pem
openssl rsa -in key.pem -outform PEM -pubout -out public.pem
```

After that, the code below is executed.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#include <cstring>
#include <openssl/bio.h>
#include <openssl/err.h>
#include <openssl/ssl.h>
const int PADDING = RSA_PKCS1_OAEP_PADDING;

RSA *createRSAWithFilename(const char *filename, int pub)
{
    FILE *fp = fopen(filename, "rb");

    if (fp == NULL)
    {
        printf("Unable to open file %s \n", filename);
        return NULL;
    }
    RSA *rsa = RSA_new();

    if (pub)
    {
        rsa = PEM_read_RSA_PUBKEY(fp, &rsa, NULL, NULL);
    }
    else
    {
        rsa = PEM_read_RSAPrivateKey(fp, &rsa, NULL, NULL);
        
    }

    return rsa;
}

int public_encrypt(unsigned char *data, int data_len, RSA *rsa, unsigned char *encrypted)
{
    int result = RSA_public_encrypt(data_len, data, encrypted, rsa, PADDING);
    return result;
}

int private_decrypt(unsigned char *enc_data, int data_len, RSA *rsa, unsigned char *decrypted)
{
    int result = RSA_private_decrypt(data_len, enc_data, decrypted, rsa, PADDING);
    return result;
}

int main()
{
    std::string textToBeEncoded="hi";
    unsigned char plaintext[1024] = {0};
    unsigned char encrypted[4098]= {0};
    unsigned char decrypted[4098]={0};
    strcpy((char *)plaintext,textToBeEncoded.c_str());

    RSA *rsaPublic=createRSAWithFilename("public.pem", 1);

    memset(encrypted,0,4098);
    int en_result=public_encrypt(plaintext, strlen((char *)plaintext), rsaPublic, encrypted);
    //fprintf(stderr, "Error: %s\n", ERR_error_string(ERR_get_error(), NULL));
    
    RSA *rsaPrivate=createRSAWithFilename("key.pem", 0);
  
    memset(decrypted,0,4098);   
    int de_result=private_decrypt(encrypted, strlen((char *)encrypted), rsaPrivate, decrypted);
    //fprintf(stderr, "Error: %s\n", ERR_error_string(ERR_get_error(), NULL));

    std::cout << "Result EN: " + std::to_string(en_result)  << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Result DE: " + std::to_string(de_result)  << std::endl;
    
    std::string decryptedString = std::string((const char *)decrypted);
    std::cout << "DECRYPTED: " + decryptedString  << " END."<< std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

At one time, the output looks okay and 0 (No error) is the only error code:

> Error: error:00000000:lib(0)::reason(0) // error code=0 after encryption
> Error: error:00000000:lib(0)::reason(0) // error code=0 after decryption
> Result EN: 256
> Result DE: 2
> DECRYPTED: hi END.

At another time, the output is this:

> Error: error:00000000:lib(0)::reason(0) // error code=0 after encryption
> Error: error:02000079:rsa routines::oaep decoding error // ERROR after decryption
> Result EN: 256
> Result DE: -1
> DECRYPTED:  END.

Can someone help?

Best regards!

Comment: **Encrypted data is binary and is not a C string.** Calling `strlen((char*)encrypted)` will frequently, effectively at random, return a value which isn't the correct size of the encrypted data, which causes decryption to fail. Instead use `en_result` if positive (-1 indicates encryption failed so you can't decrypt at all) or simply 256 because any RSA 2048-bit key will _always_ produce a 256-byte cryptogram; see the specifications using I2OSP in PKCS1. Similarly attempting to print the encrypted value with `cout <<` will never produce usable results.

Comment: Hi Dave, 
this solved the issue for my local en- and decryption, thank you very much!

Comment: Hey, we encountered another issue, maybe this is an easy question for you: Could you give us another hint on how to parse the encoded data to an unsigned char array and then back to the required OSP format? We are trying to send the encoded data and decode it elsewhere, however somewhere during our workflow the data seems to get altered, as the recipient is not able to decode.

Comment: The format is just OS = Octet String (no P) -- String here in the general meaning, an ordered sequence, not a C string specifically -- so an unsigned char array  (or part of one) _is_ an octet string. Your question as posted has nothing to do with sending data anywhere and StackExchange (including StackOVerflow) is not a chat room, but even if you asked something that vague as a question, there are millions of ways of sending data and billions of ways to get it right or wrong, so there is absolutely no chance I could fit an answer on Stack or finish it during my lifetime.